# Ghost user? A user doesn't show up on the login screen nor in "users" command

Tags: linux-mint, users

There is a user in my (Mint 17) system that I can log into by typing the name and the password. But it doesn't show up in any list of users I can think of, be it the login screen or the output of `users`. I can also see all my sessions with this user with `last`

How can this be possible?

UPD: also, it seems that with some login themes I can't log into this user. Some of the themes check the username against a list somewhere and others don't, I guess.

Comment: What about `getent passwd that-user-name`?

Comment: Perchance might you enlighten us with the **name** of this user?  Bob? Rumplestilsken? Clarence?  (Oh, and `users` only shows the names of currently logged in users)

Comment: I'm assuming you're not working on a company-scale system (which might get users from a centralized LDAP or Active Directory service)?

Comment: @muru username:x:1002:1002:/home/username

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz No, it's my personal laptop, everything is local. Or, at least, should be.

Comment: That passwd entry looks weird – I'd expect seven entries, separated by `:`: user name, x (used to be password), uid, gid, user's human-readable name (GECOS), home directory, shell. You entry seems to be missing GECOS and the shell. Not having a valid default shell would explain why you can't log in with it.

Comment: In the end, any user can be logged into a normally configured linux system when any of the modules activated via the config files in /etc/pam.d/* accepts the username and authentication presented, and can decide on an initial uid and gid to log that user in with . That is enough for the kernel, which doesn't ever know users by name. All the stuff that translates uids to names comes together in nsswitch.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution thanks to the comment by @UlrichSchwarz. It turns out that this user didn't have a default shell. So I fixed it with

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash username
```

Thanks for advice!