# Is `users` guaranteed to indicate all users on host?

Tags: linux, security

I have what I believe to be a very basic question about Linux hosts:

Is the `users` command guaranteed to indicate all of the users on the host, or are there ways for users to hide the fact that they're active on the host at that time?

If the latter is the case, does anyone know of techniques users can use to hide their user from the results in the users command output?

Any ideas others can offer on this question would be very helpful.

Comment: Guess this depends on how one defines, being on the host.

Comment: @llua, intriguing. By being on the host I mean being able to execute system commands and having access to system files. But I'm interested to hear where you're headed...

Comment: @duhaime As thrig's answer mentions, it's possible to execute commands in a variety of ways without actually being logged into the system. So perhaps, the question needs to be clarified as far as  what you're really interested in - actual presence of a user on the system, or the ability to run commands. In later case, `users` won't help you much in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `users` utility is very small program written in C - it's about 150 lines of code only. Since it's part of [GNU core utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html), you [can download](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/) the utilities and read the code from `users.c` file.

Infact by default the `users` utility is only wrapper for `utmp` and `wtmp`. There are two obvious basic approaches to hide the fact that a user is logged in.

The first approach is to change code of the `users` utility and replace binary `/usr/bin/users`.

The second approach is to wipe the traces from the `utmp`, `wtmp`,`lastlog`, `utmpx`, `wtmpx` etc. logfiles that may exist on *nix systems. There are log-wiper tools available for this approach like `cloak`, `zap`, `clear` etc. [Read part 3.4 carefully](http://www.theparticle.com/files/txt/hacking/hackingunix/hacking_unix-part3.txt) from 'AFTER THE BREAK-IN' in 'HACKING UNIX'.

Of course, there are many another ways to avoid writing to `utmp` and `wtmp` files for particular applications and users, [read this example](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/exclude-a-from-being-logged-in-var-log-wtmp-920865/#post4560062) for `ssh`.

Some additional basic and common logging options for `login` can be configured in the file:

```
/etc/login.defs
```

To understand deeper from admin and user point of view where `users` utility parses its information, just explore the files:

```
utmpdump /var/run/utmp
utmpdump /var/log/wtmp
sudo utmpdump /var/log/btmp
```

Additionally pay your attention to the note in [UTMP(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html) and [WTMP(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/wtmp) man:

> Unlike various other systems, where utmp logging can be disabled by
>   removing the file, utmp must always exist on Linux. If you want to
>   disable who(1), then do not make utmp world readable.
>
> The file format is machine-dependent, so it is recommended that it be
>   processed only on the machine architecture where it was created.

So, the answer for the question: 'Is this possible to hide from the `users` utility the fact a user is logged in?', - is YES, it's possible. The definite approach depends on definite situation - it depends on level of access to a *nix-system etc.

Comment: this answer if fantastic and makes me wish StackExchange would allow one to accept multiple answers. I hadn't thought about the fact that one could simply rewrite the binary itself! Thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

It is trivial to be "able to execute system commands and having access to system files" on a system without appearing in the `/var/run/utmp` file that `users(1)` reads.

```
$ ssh testhost sh
```

for instance creates no indication from `users` on a Centos 7 `testhost` that someone is running `sh` which is quite capable of executing system commands and accessing system files:

```
# users
root
# pstree | grep -3 'sh$'
        |-sshd-+-sshd---sshd
        |      |-sshd---bash-+-grep
        |      |             `-pstree
        |      `-sshd---sshd---sh
        |-sssd-+-sssd_be
        |      `-sssd_nss
        |-systemd-journal
```

Another way: run a shell at some high port with `socat` or something. Another way: run a webserver that accepts commands, runs them, and returns the results. Another way: schedule commands in advance with `at(1)` then logout.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes. This includes those physically logged in and from remote hosts.

From `man users`:

> Output who is currently logged in according to FILE. If FILE is not specified, use /var/run/utmp

The [utmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html) database includes `char    ut_host[UT_HOSTSIZE];` for remote host login information.

However, in case where user doesn't have a login shell, it may not show up in `users` output, as was apparently the case in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245724/85039).